# Map with polygons evolution over time

Tags: carto, carto-js

I want to put a button on a map with polygons so that you can see an evolution over time. The problem is that clicking on these buttons is not getting any response.

It also happens that the provinces are representing the date of the years at a time, we see the date for 2007 and the rest of 2016. Another problem is that pop-ups don't look with the Style I've in the builder.

This is the map:[image]

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>

<style>
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: o;
  width: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
#slider {
position: absolute;
bottom: 40px;
right: 40px;
left: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="2007">2007</button>
  <button class="2008">2008</button>
  <button class="2009">2009</button>
  <button class="2010">2010</button>
  <button class="2011">2011</button>
  <button class="2012">2012</button>
  <button class="2013">2013</button>
  <button class="2014">2014</button>
  <button class="2015">2015</button>
  <button class="2016">2016</button>

  <script>
    var ProvinciasLayer;
  $(document).ready(function () {
  cartodb.createVis('map',
'https://master-periodismo-datos.carto.com/u/nicolmontilla/api/v2/viz/0ba2b2c6-2d36-11e7-84e5-0ecd1babdde5/viz.json')
.done(function (vis, layers) {
ProvinciasLayer = layers[1].getSubLayer(0);
});
$('.2007').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2007'");
});
$('.2008').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2008'");
});
$('.2009').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2009'");
});
$('.2010').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2010'");
});
$('.2011').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2011'");
});
$('.2012').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2012'");
});
$('.2013').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2013'");
});
$('.2014').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2014'");
});
$('.2015').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2015'");
});
$('.2016').click(function(){ProvinciasLayer.setSQL("select * from violencia_de_genero_1 where ano = '2016'");
});
})
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share the code and errors you are getting?

Comment: I just share the code. if you need anything else ask me please. I'm new in Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are using a `vizjson` from a BUILDER map with the current version of CARTO.js. As mentioned [here](https://carto.com/learn/guides/intro/migrating-from-carto-editor-to-carto-builder#temporary-limitations), they are not compatible. But the good news is that you do not need to code because BUILDER allows you to add widgets for dynamic filtering.

You can filter by year with two widgets:

a) **Years as categories**. First, go to `DATA` tab and click on the checkbox to add a widget for your `year` field (in your case, `ano`). Second, click on `EDIT` and change the widget type from histogram to category. The problem is that the values/years are not showed in the right ordered.

b) **Years as date**. Go to your dataset and change the data type from numeric to date. You can also do this using a SQL query like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET year_field = to_timestamp(year_field::text, 'YYYY')
```

Go back to your map click on `DATA` and add a widget for your year field, but this time change the type of the widget to times series. Edit the widget and reduce the number of buckets (`9` in your case) in order to match the number of years.